# MongoDb Atlas Full text search index rebuilding without downtime

Tags: mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I'm looking for the best approach for making changes (adding new fields) to a production setup full-text search index (added in 4.2)  without having any downtime and affecting my clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only way to accomplish this would be to create a 2nd index with your new definition, and then switch over in your application when the build is complete, and then delete the first index.

Comment: This answer needs to be updated because Atlas Search no supports no downtime re-indexing as long as you have enough disk spaces to support two copies of a search index.